# position one widget under another in footer, in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm trying to put my social media widget under my contact information widget (in the footer of the page), and not next to each other, because social media widget is very tiny to have own column, but I can't find a way to make it work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out plugins which allows you to add custom widget area. One very good tutorial is [here](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/add-widget-areas-to-wordpress-guide/)

By using these plugins you can add custom widget area anywhere in your blog.
Try to put your social media widget under any of these custom widget area.